# if/else for non-duplicate of data

Tags: php, loops, duplicates, if-statement

Im having a problem, it seems my codes are incorrect. All i want is that to prevent the duplication of data. In this array submit form result, if the user already have already the kind of row, he can only insert data that are not in the table. My current code will not insert all data. But if remove the if else statements, all the data within the loop can be inserted.

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $var_emp_id = $_POST["emp_id"];
        $var_task_id = $_POST["task_id"];
        $var_weight = $_POST['weight'];
        $submit=$_POST['submit'];

        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($var_emp_id); $i++)
        {
            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT emp_id,task_id FROM peval_tbl WHERE emp_id = '$var_emp_id[$i]' AND task_id = '$task_id[$i]'");

            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
            {

                $emp_id = $row['emp_id'];
                $task_id = $row['task_id'];

                if ($var_emp_id[$i] ==  $emp_id && $var_task_id[$i] == $task_id){
                mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO peval_tbl(weight,task_id,emp_id)                         VALUES('$var_weight[$i]','$var_task_id[$i]','$var_emp_id[$i]')");                                  

            }
        else{   
            error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

            for ($i = 0; $i <= count($var_emp_id); $i++)
        {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO peval_tbl(weight,task_id,emp_id)                         VALUES('$var_weight[$i]','$var_task_id[$i]','$var_emp_id[$i]')");

        }
        }
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting a primary key on the table on the column(s) that are unique, then using an INSERT IGNORE query to load (IGNORE so it doesn't throw an error on duplicates).